# Setting output resolution of kde object

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly set the output resolution of a kde object created using the kde function in the ks library in R. Basically, I have some SpatialPoints objects that I am feeding into kde and converting the output to a raster. I want the cells of this raster to have a specific resolution.

Here's an example using the meuse data set, as requested.

```
library(ks)
library(raster)
data(meuse)
points = data.frame(meuse$x,meuse$y)
raster(kde(points,Hlscv(points)))
```

The output I get from this code is:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 151, 151, 22801  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 31.37394, 46.03558  (x, y) 
extent      : 177628.8, 182366.2, 328186.8, 335138.2  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
projection  : NA 
values      : in memory
min value   : 0 
max value   : 2.925851e-07
```

I want to find a way to set the output resolution (third row of output) to be what I want.

Now I know that kde has 'gridsize' and 'bgridsize' options and to use these you set the number of points/cells you want in each dimension. However, without knowing the extent of the output you cannot calculate the number of cells to get a specific resolution.

One thought I've had is to use the H-value in the appropriate dimension to buffer the min and max coordinates of each dimension and pre-derive the extent for the kde output. However, I think this would only work with diagonal matrices for H and so I am not sure it could be implementable with a full 2x2 H-value matrix.

I am also aware that you can resample a raster but I want to ensure that I am not coming from a lower resolution kde object.

Comment: Wouldn't you just divide the `range`(s) by the "resolution" to get the parameters for `gridsize`(s)?

Comment: Maybe it isn't clear enough in the question, but I have no way of knowing the ranges until the command is run.

Comment: You make a function that takes the data, you calculate the ranges, then you call the `kde` function from inside that function.

Comment: You need at a minimum to edit your question to include: `str(coordinates(spdf))`

Comment: I don't see how that will help. spdf@coords is a standard two column matrix as defined by the SpatialPointsDataFrame class declaration.

Comment: I'm giving up. My efforts to get more specificity about your data situation are failing. When I plot the value of that code given the "meuse" dataset in package `sp` I get sensible output. I cannot figure out what you are trying to do with your data.  I'd be happy to delete all of my comments and questions if you want.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is not clear. For an example, run the command raster(kde(data.frame(meuse$x,meuse$y),Hlscv(data.frame(meuse$x,meuse$y)))) after loading the meuse data set. The output gives info about the raster, including its resolution in both x and y directions. I want these resolutions to be a specific number that I set.

Comment: Gives me an error. Why don't you rewrite your question using the "meuse" dataset instead of making us guess at what you are talking about.

Comment: OK, I edited it as you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was poking around and noticed that there was a consistent relationship between the increase in extent of the output kde raster compared to the input points and the H parameters. I don't know why this is the case (if it is due to the implementation or the math behind things), so it may not hold for all cases, but it works consistently for me, so I'm passing it on. Specifically, I found that (this is an equation, not code):

```
(range(coordinates(output)) - range(coordinates(input))) / H = ~7.4 for each dimension.
```

Consider the following code:

```
for (i in seq(1:10)){
    pts = data.frame(x=rnorm(100,300000,2500),y=rnorm(100,4000000,2500))
    rangePtsX <- diff(range(pts$x))
    rangePtsY <- diff(range(pts$y))
    H  <- Hlscv(pts)
    ras <- raster(kde(pts,H))
    rangeRasX <- xmax(ras) - xmin(ras)
    rangeRasY <- ymax(ras) - ymin(ras)
    rangeDiffX <- rangeRasX - rangePtsX
    rangeDiffY <- rangeRasY - rangePtsY
    print(paste("rangeDiffX/hX:",rangeDiffX/sqrt(H[1,1]),"rangeDiffY/hY:",rangeDiffY/sqrt(H[2,2])))
}
```

The output of this is:

```
[1] "rangeDiffX/hX: 7.37104456534156 rangeDiffY/hY: 7.37763153209006"
[1] "rangeDiffX/hX: 7.39015683159216 rangeDiffY/hY: 7.39151926375274"
[1] "rangeDiffX/hX: 7.39492769120192 rangeDiffY/hY: 7.39414077521017"
[1] "rangeDiffX/hX: 7.39909462708713 rangeDiffY/hY: 7.39917867776494"
[1] "rangeDiffX/hX: 7.39801448966617 rangeDiffY/hY: 7.39779576937998"
[1] "rangeDiffX/hX: 7.39679742756067 rangeDiffY/hY: 7.39745249174806"
[1] "rangeDiffX/hX: 7.39405975028797 rangeDiffY/hY: 7.39368126656615"
[1] "rangeDiffX/hX: 7.3913950522465 rangeDiffY/hY: 7.38980236385133"
[1] "rangeDiffX/hX: 7.39988585440102 rangeDiffY/hY: 7.39988850314936"
[1] "rangeDiffX/hX: 7.39529001635855 rangeDiffY/hY: 7.39475036015628"
```

From there it was simple to write a function to calculate the optimum number of cells:

```
gridSize <- function(pts,H,res){
    sizeX <- (diff(range(pts[,1])) + (7.4 * sqrt(H[1,1]))) / res
    sizeY <- (diff(range(pts[,2])) + (7.4 * sqrt(H[2,2]))) / res
    c(sizeX,sizeY)
}
```

This works for different selectors as well:

```
for (hMethod in c("Hlscv","Hlscv.diag","Hscv","Hpi","Hpi.diag")){
    for (i in seq(1:5)){
        pts <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100,300000,2500),y=rnorm(100,4000000,2500))
        ras <- raster(kde(pts,eval(call(hMethod,x=pts)),gridsize=gridSize(pts,H,30)))
        print(paste("xres:",xres(ras),"yres:",yres(ras)))
    }
}
```

produces:

```
    [1] "xres: 29.8498137761045 yres: 29.8456700392426"
    [1] "xres: 29.9573491524671 yres: 29.9874090657282"
    [1] "xres: 29.968525344047 yres: 29.9580897162408"
    [1] "xres: 29.9498803408057 yres: 29.964382664777"
    [1] "xres: 29.9711108728299 yres: 29.9773401860409"
    [1] "xres: 29.9950831714231 yres: 29.9658642153949"
    [1] "xres: 29.9905564968586 yres: 29.982738272666"
    [1] "xres: 29.9527729769381 yres: 29.9855591986985"
    [1] "xres: 29.9786535322154 yres: 29.9594421322198"
    [1] "xres: 29.9461263582666 yres: 29.9587155045891"
    [1] "xres: 32.1494143184879 yres: 31.9656619568261"
    [1] "xres: 31.3425525696929 yres: 31.7046601198584"
    [1] "xres: 31.9515186102478 yres: 31.9042586036464"
    [1] "xres: 31.5043829006183 yres: 30.0677630099221"
    [1] "xres: 31.1816325999623 yres: 30.782974425409"
    [1] "xres: 29.4406922338173 yres: 28.70952461795"
    [1] "xres: 31.0945577583419 yres: 31.2995894646556"
    [1] "xres: 29.3060327529272 yres: 29.4708662690499"
    [1] "xres: 29.502732054192 yres: 29.3034911939017"
    [1] "xres: 30.0529058397693 yres: 29.2893540247008"
    [1] "xres: 27.7898933275596 yres: 29.1928490584976"
    [1] "xres: 27.7628745096943 yres: 27.5794864810828"
    [1] "xres: 28.9513504972817 yres: 29.7665791290592"
    [1] "xres: 28.9569389967698 yres: 29.2103688932787"
    [1] "xres: 28.6005579365073 yres: 29.3701912564357"
```

Which produces results very close to the value of 30 that I wanted (there is error inherent in choosing an integer number of grid cells in the kde). If I want a more exact resolution, I can resample / disaggregate the raster from here.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my first comment I thought that : gridsize= range/resolution, so illustrated below a relatively fine grid (chosen to have what I thought would be comparable resolution to the default) and then demonstrated a coarser grid. As blindJesse points out, the units for "resolution" are more complex than I realized. At this point I would advise bindJesse to start drafting a letter to the Spatial-R mailing list:

```
 gridsize.x <- diff(range(meuse@coords[,"x"]))/35
 gridsize.y <- diff(range(meuse@coords[,"y"]))/35
 gridsize.x
#[1] 79.57143
 gridsize.y
# [1] 111.3429
 rimage <- raster(kde(coordinates(meuse),Hlscv(coordinates(meuse)), 
                                  gridsize=c(gridsize.x,gridsize.y) ))
 plot(rimage)
```

[image]

```
 gridsize.y <- diff(range(meuse@coords[,"y"]))/70
 gridsize.x <- diff(range(meuse@coords[,"x"]))/70
 rimage <- raster(kde(coordinates(meuse),Hlscv(coordinates(meuse)), 
         gridsize=c(gridsize.x,gridsize.y) ))
 plot(rimage)
```

[image]

Comment: This would be fine if the output of kde had the same extent as the input points, but it doesn't. You can see for yourself that the output resolution of your examples is nowhere near what you tried to set it to be. So yes, this would work in a general way, but not in setting a specific output resolution.